# How to stop actionButton counter at zero?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which outputs the sum of clicks for two action buttons {+1, -1}. Can someone tell me how I can make the minimum value of the counter stop at zero. For example, if the first two clicks from a new session are Remove1 and Remove 1, the output will be 0, rather than -2?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add 1"),
  actionButton("remove", "Remove 1"),
  textOutput("counter")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$counter <- renderText(
    input$add + input$remove * -1
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `max(input$add + input$remove * -1,0)`

Comment: This would display a value of 0 even after clicking one more time on Remove, but one would need to click twice on Add to go to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can not change the value of an `actionButton`.

Instead you can use `reactiveVal()` like this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  total <- reactiveVal( 0 )
  observeEvent( input$add, total( total() + 1 ))
  observeEvent( input$remove, total( max( 0, total() - 1 )))
  
  output$counter <- renderText( total() )
}
```